# Write Native SQL inside JPQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Consider 2 tables `TableA` and `TableB` with M:N relationship and mapping table connecting them (for example `TableAB`). Only one has an `@Entity` object representation in the code and I would like to keep it that way (let's say other tables are only used by other app).

Is it possible to write some native SQL part of command within the JPQL with code referencing to non-existing entity in java?

Something like:

```sql
select a
from TableA a
join TableAB ab on a.id = ab.id       -- this part won't work as there is no TableAB entity in the code
where ab.someOtherColumn = :param     -- this would be problematic too
```

Comment: Hibernate ORM 6 has an `sql` function that maybe can help: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-function-sql I'm not sure because I've never used it

Comment: @DavideD'Alto, oh, cool. I was just about to post that Hibernate doesn't have that feature, and turns out they do. OP just has to be aware that this is an engine-specific feature and not part of JPQL standard. (i.e. Hibernate has it, EclipseLink has it, but some other persistence engine might not, so switching will be harder).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any JPA framework such as spring-boot-starter-data-jpa?

If so it provides the `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` annotation which offers a "nativeQuery" boolean.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username", nativeQuery = true)
User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

+`org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param`

Comment: unfortunately, the app is written in Java EE without any framework like this....this still doesn't answer my OP, which was focusing on combining JPQL and Native SQL